# Laravel 6 eager loading using with() on a belongsTo relationship is only *sometimes* returning null

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-6, eager-loading

I am working on a project where we have a model for a service provider, the type of care provided, and the status:

Provider:

```
class Provider extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'providers';

    public function status() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Status');
    }

    public function caretype() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\CareType', 'id');
    }
}
```

CareType:

```
class CareType extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'type_of_care';

    public function providers() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Providers', 'type_of_care_id');
    }

    public function category() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\CareCategory');
    }
}
```

Status:

```
class Status extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'status';

    public function providers() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Providers');
    }
}
```

On the my `SearchController` (the controller that processes search requests for providers), the `show()` function using eager loading retrieves the `caretype` perfectly. But on the `search()` function that lists the collection of search results, the `caretype` is always listed as null.

I don't understand why it would be working in one function but not the other, especially when the code to eager load is exactly the same in both functions:

```
public function search(Request $request)
    {

        $validated = $request->validate([
            //I removed the validation code for this post
        ]);

        $providers = Provider::with(['status', 'caretype'])->get();

        return view('search.results', ['providers' => $providers]);

    }

    public function show($id)
    {

        $single_provider = Provider::with(['status', 'caretype'])->where('id', $id)->first();
        return view('search.details', ['provider' => $single_provider]);

    }
```

Any help in this would be appreciated. I know that the model and relationship foreign keys are properly defined because the `show()` function is able to get the `caretype` just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nope. your relationship and foreign keys are not correct. as from the [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse)

> Eloquent determines the default foreign key name by examining the name of the relationship method and suffixing the method name with a `_` followed by the name of the primary key column. However, if the foreign key on the Child model is not like that, you may pass a custom key name as the second argument to the belongsTo method.

you are passing the `id` column as the foreign key in `Provider` model's `caretype` ralation but your foreign key is `type_of_care_id`. so you are getting some results when the id matches but if not, you are getting null. change your relationship code to

```
public function caretype()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\CareType', 'type_of_care_id');
}
```

now again from the doc

> If your parent model does not use `id` as its primary key, or you wish to join the child model to a different column, you may pass a third argument to the `belongsTo` method specifying your parent table's custom key.

in your case `id` is the primary key. so you don't have to pass the third parameter. just update the primary key reference and everything will work perfectly.

Comment: Oh my gosh I completely mixed up the direction of the relationship in the model. This fixed it. Thank you!